# Correctly rotate web images using Square's Picasso

Tags: android, rotation, exif, picasso

I am using Square's Picasso to load images from my server into the app.  These are jpgs.  I've seen that [EXIF tags are not supported in the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468098/reading-exif-data-from-byte-array-in-android).  I was wondering if anyone had managed to write their own rotation code to use in conjunction with Picasso to correctly rotate portrait images?