# Photo rotated from camera (SAMSUNG device)

Tags: android, camera, samsung-galaxy

i hate this company. All them devices have a lot of bugs. Ok question :
Im trying to fix stupid problem  (which as i know exist more than 5 years)
Its photo taken from camera - rotated on 90 degree.
I have two devices :

```
  Nexus 5p and Samsung j2  
  Nexus - work perfect. Everything fine. 
  Samsung - photo rotated
```

For example :

```
Photo size - nexus : Portrate : width 1000, height 1900.  Landscape :
width 1900 , height 1000
```

Lets see on samsung device :

```
Photo size  - Portrate: width 1900(?????) height - 1000(????)
rotate to landscape : width 1900 height 1000
```

After some testing : if make photo in landscape mode on samsung device - than everything ok. Photo not rotated

If make photo in PORTRATE - photo rotated on 90 degree. (BUT size of photo as on landscape (HOW ITS POSSIBLE) ?

Anyone know how to fix this stupid bug ? Maybe any can tell me how to detect orientation for camera ? Im using IntentActivity for photo :

```
String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + File.separator + "camera_img.jpg";
                            File file = new File(_path);
                            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Any help  ?
I also add a checker , if its samsung device than rotate. But rotation good only if we create photo in portrate mode. In landscape everything fine. So i need somehow detected in which orientation photo was created. Any one know ?

Comment: I faced same problem please refer following link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-does-an-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-on-a

Comment: @DhruvPatel its not working because photo size always in landscape size.

Comment: Can you put a landscape and a portrait file somewhere on the internet so we can have a look?

Comment: in a simple way you can use glide to get bitmap or directly to set in imageView as https://stackoverflow.com/a/68029909/9326166

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPD 29.08.2018** I found that this method doesn't work with Samsung device based on Android 8+. I don't have Samsung s8 (for example) and can't understand why this again does not work there.  If someone can test and check why this not work - let's try to fix this together.

---

I found how to fix: well it's really stupid and very hard for me.

First step get activity result

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "TakenFromCamera.jpg";
            String p1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            String fName = "/TakenFromCamera.jpg";
            final int rotation = getImageOrientation(_path);
            File file = resaveBitmap(p1, fName, rotation);
            Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path);
```

Main steps it's `getImageOrientation` before changes in file.

1. `getImageOrientation` (by path)
2. resave file (if need send to server, if you need only for preview we can skip this step)
3. get correct bitmap from file

For preview it's enough to perform only steps 1 and 3, and using this function - just rotate bitmap.

```
private Bitmap checkRotationFromCamera(Bitmap bitmap, String pathToFile, int rotate) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotate);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return rotatedBitmap;
    }
```

getImageOrientation

```
public static int getImageOrientation(String imagePath) {
    int rotate = 0;
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rotate;
}
```

and resaveBitmap if need

```
private File resaveBitmap(String path, String filename, int rotation) { //help for fix landscape photos
        String extStorageDirectory = path;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        File file = new File(filename);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
            file = new File(extStorageDirectory, filename);
        }
        try {
            // make a new bitmap from your file
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + filename);
            bitmap = checkRotationFromCamera(bitmap, path + filename, rotation);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) ((float) bitmap.getWidth() * 0.3f), (int) ((float) bitmap.getHeight() * 0.3f), false);
            bitmap = Utils.getCircleImage(bitmap);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Comment: Check out my answer, it works with Samsung S8.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261434/photo-rotated-from-camera-samsung-device/57460550#57460550

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rotate an image but you only have the byte array, you can use this:

```
private byte[] rotationFromCamera(byte[] data) {
    int rotation = Exif.getOrientation(data);
    if(rotation == 0) return data;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, null);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(rotation);
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

and this exif util from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468098/reading-exif-data-from-byte-array-in-android)

This is a bit slow if the image is large.

Answer (score 2):

Found this [here](https://www.oipapio.com/question-7073106), works for me Samsung S8.

```
static final String[] CONTENT_ORIENTATION = new String[] {
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION
    };


public static int getExifOrientation(Context context, Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
        id = id.split(":")[1];
        cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                CONTENT_ORIENTATION, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
        if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
        // If the orientation column doesn't exist, assume no rotation.
        return 0;
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This works when I get the image from Gallery `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Tested it with `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, and it returned 0. But maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking the picture yourself with the camera API ?
If so you can get the orientation with:
Camera1 API :

```
CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
int sensorOrientation = cameraInfo.orientation;
```

Camera2 API :

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = mCameraCharacteristics;
int sensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
```

Comment: Read my post carefully , im write there : im using intentActivity  not Camera Api.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you should use the EXIF to see the image rotation then

Answer (score 0):

Using [Glide lib](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) could solve the issue

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO_FOR_PROFILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        try {
           Glide.with(this).load(data.getData()).into(mProfileFragment.mProfileImage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Utils.handleException(e);
        }
}
```