# Picasso image gets rotated by itself

Tags: android, picasso

I am using the Picasso library as follows, but when I take image and put into ImageView, image gets rotated. I wonder what might cause the issue?

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewUser"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description" />

 imageViewUser = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewUser);

 Picasso.get().load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.image)
              .error(R.drawable.blank_profile)
              .resize(100, 100)
              .centerCrop()
              .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
              .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
              .into(imageViewUser);
```

Comment: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/846

Comment: IOW, what sort of image is it (e.g., a photo) and where is it coming from?

Comment: @CommonsWare, the image is coming from camera.

Comment: Use the image as a bitmap!

Comment: Then most likely the image has EXIF headers telling image viewers to rotate the image. Image loaders like Glide and Picasso tend to honor those headers. You can use offline tools (e.g,. `exiftool`) or Web sites (e.g., http://metapicz.com/) to examine the EXIF headers of an image.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's happened on some Samsung devices. One way is to manually rotate the needed image. Read more [Photo rotated from camera (SAMSUNG device)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261434/photo-rotated-from-camera-samsung-device)